# MVC Windows Authentication causing querystring too long error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ldap

I have an MVC web site that I’d like to modify so instead of using forms to log the user in, it picks up their windows id then passes this to a local Active Directory using LDAP.

However, when I change IIS from Anonymous to Windows Authentication and change the code in Start.Auth.cs with the following (where LoginUser is the script that picks up the user and connects to AD)…

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LoginUser")
});
```

…it causes a querystring is too long browser error …

http://localhost:80/UserAuthentication/Account/LoginUser?ReturnUrl=%2FUserAuthentication%2FAccount%2FLoginUser%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FUserAuthentication%252FAccount%252FLoginUser%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FUserAuthentication%25252FAccount%25252FLoginUser%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FUserAuthentication%2525252FAccount%2525252FLoginUser%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FUserAuthentication%252525252FAccount%252525252FLoginUser%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D% (etc)

I have placed [AllowAnonymous] above the LoginUser script so I’m really not sure why it won’t go into it (as this what looks like is happening again and again).

Any help would really really be most appreciated.

Updated to include LoginUser script:
I've included a stripped down version of it that just logs a user in.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoginUser()
{
    var status = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("ATHORNE", "Something123!", false, false);

    return View();
}
```

I am using PasswordSignInAsync with a constant password because there would not be a password for Windows Authentication.  If there is a better way, please let me know!

The View is the blank default view at the moment.

Comment: can you show your authentication controller and View?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the script requested.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would override `OnActionExcuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)`

You can do this in a base Controller class or in an [Action Filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

If IIS is set to deny Anonymous Access and enable Windows authentication then within the filter context you can access the users' identity via `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;`

To be a bit safer you could write some code like

```
var user = (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity != null 
    && filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ?
    HttpContext.User.Identity.Name : null;
```

If username is not null then you have the currently logged on authenticated user, in the form domain\username. You can query Active Directory based on this to get any other information you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I removed `LoginPath` from `Startup.Auth.cs` and used override void `OnActionExecuting` in the `BaseController`. I was then able to use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to get the user id.  I do then however need to set up the User object. I was going to use `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` to do this (with a constant password) but this requires the objects that are passed into `AccountController` i.e. `ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationSignInManager`  ... How can I set up the User object so the user is logged in from within that script in the `BaseController`?

Comment: The user is basically already logged in. There is no need for a separate Account Controller. You can look at Authorize Attributes for different controllers or actions, or you can retrieve the User object and store is in the base controller for reference in later actions.